# What does it mean when psql has blank database access privileges?

Tags: postgresql

When I run `\l+` in `psql` to get a list of all databases and their access privileges, I see that some of the databases have blank access privileges. What does it mean when the `Access privileges` column is blank in `psql`?

If there is some sort of default, how can I see what that default is?

```
me=# \l+
                                                                      List of databases
    Name     |    Owner    | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   |  Size   | Tablespace |                Description                 
-------------+-------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------+---------+------------+--------------------------------------------
 me          | me          | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |                       | 7239 kB | pg_default | 
 postgres    | postgres    | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |                       | 7151 kB | pg_default | default administrative connection database
 template0   | postgres    | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +| 7041 kB | pg_default | unmodifiable empty database
             |             |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres |         |            | 
 template1   | postgres    | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +| 7041 kB | pg_default | default template for new databases
             |             |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres |         |            | 
(4 rows)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> *What does it mean when the Access privileges column is blank*

[Quote from the manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html#PRIVILEGE-ABBREVS-TABLE)

> If the "Access privileges" column is empty for a given object, it means the object has default privileges (that is, its privileges column is null). Default privileges always include all privileges for the owner, and can include some privileges for PUBLIC depending on the object type, as explained above

The default privileges are also documented there

> PostgreSQL grants privileges on some types of objects to PUBLIC by default when the objects are created. No privileges are granted to PUBLIC by default on tables, table columns, sequences, foreign data wrappers, foreign servers, large objects, schemas, or tablespaces. For other types of objects, the default privileges granted to PUBLIC are as follows: CONNECT and TEMPORARY (create temporary tables) privileges for databases; EXECUTE privilege for functions and procedures; and USAGE privilege for languages and data types (including domains).

Comment: How can I see what that default is?

Comment: That's also explained in the manual ("as explained above") - just read the link

Comment: The linked docs says, "Note: for this purpose, 'default privileges' always means the built-in default privileges for the object's type. An object whose privileges have been affected by an ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES command will always be shown with an explicit privilege entry that includes the effects of the ALTER." I had thought a blank column meant "default" and that what "default" means could be altered. Do I understand correctly that a blank privilege column always means the same thing regardless of the database state?

Comment: The "quote from the manual" link takes to current version, but documentation has changed since 2017. I guess it was pointing to v10, which `GRANT` section is longer than current v13 as part of the explanatios seems to be moved to `Privileges` section

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Does that mean there is no possible way to revert back to using implicit privileges? If possible, I'd like the role to always use the default (or null) privileges, although after accidentally running a GRANT, its access privileges are now explicit